# Can I do a Perforce integrate without syncing the entire stream?

Tags: perforce-integrate, perforce-stream

Let's say I have two 100GB Perforce Streams: A and B. A is the parent B and only supports one-direction merging.

My goal is to setup regular automation to merge changes in Stream A down to Stream B. However, to do this, [it looks like](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_integrate.html) I have to create and sync the entire 100GB workspace for Stream B, then run a `p4 integrate` command to merge all the changes from Stream A, even if only a few files were changed in the parent! I can circumvent this sync issue slightly by using the same workspace after the initial sync, but this runs into scaling issues in terms of space and sync time as I add Stream C or D.

In sum: is there any way for me to create a workspace and create an integrate changelist such that I'm only syncing the minimal amount of files needed to create said integrate changelist, or am I out of luck?